# Quick sort logic

Tags: sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement **quick sort** in java and I have one doubt. So here's my quick sort code:

```
package com.sorting;

public class QuickSort implements Sort {

@Override
public int [] sort(int[] arr) {
    return quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

private int [] quickSort(int[] numbers, int low, int high) {

    if (low < high) {
        int q = partitionTheArrayAroundPivot(numbers, low, high);

        if (low < q)
            quickSort(numbers, low, q);

        if ((q+1) < high)
            quickSort(numbers, q + 1, high);
    }

    return numbers;
}

private int partitionTheArrayAroundPivot(int[] numbers, int low, int high) {

    int pivot = selectPivot(numbers, low, high);
    int i = low;
    int j = high;

    while (true) {

            while (numbers[i] < pivot) {
            i++;
        }

            while (numbers[j] > pivot) {
            j--;
        }

        if ( i <= j) {
            swap(numbers, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        } else {
            return j;
        }

    }

}

private int selectPivot(int[] numbers, int low, int high) {
    return numbers[high];
}

private void swap(int[] numbers, int i, int j) {
    int temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = temp;
}

}
```

**Doubt 1:** We keep increasing the index i till we hit a number which is >= pivot

```
while (numbers[i] < pivot)
    i++;
```

Similarly we keep decreasing the index `j` till we hit a number which is <= pivot

```
while (numbers[j] > pivot)
    j--;
```

So, this means that both indexes will also come out of the loop if both hits pivots at two different places e.g. 1,0,1 here if pivot is 1, then i will be 0 and j will be 2. And the below condition will be satisfied
    if (i <= j) {
        ....
    }
    but in that case it won't be able to sort the above array (1,0,1) because after swapping we are increasing i and decreasing j so the value become i = j = 1. After that i will hit the third element i.e 1 and will again come out of the loop with value i = 2 and similarly j = 0 and we will not be able to sort the array.

So where's the problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Are you asking *if* your code works?  Or are you asking *why* your code works?  Or something else?

Comment: my code is not working for the case I mentioned above... so what's the problem in the code...

Comment: In that case, you should use the debugger to step through your code to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I debugged it and then only I came to know about the scenario {1,0,1} where pivot is 1 and it's failing ... so how to handle these kind of scenarios in quick sort algo

Comment: Did you try the code in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the code a little so that selectPivot returns the index instead:

```
private int selectPivotIndex(int[] numbers, int low, int high) {
    return high;
}
```

Then the partitioning funcion can move the pivot aside, and sort the remaining items according to pivot value. A single loop will do it, in this implementation duplicate pivots will end up on right side:

```
private int partitionTheArrayAroundPivot(int[] numbers, int low, int high) {

    int pivotIndex = selectPivotIndex(numbers, low, high);

    swap(numbers, pivotIndex, high); // Not needed if selectPivotIndex always returns high
    int newPivotIndex = low;
    for(int i = low; i < high; i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] < numbers[pivotIndex])
        {
            swap(numbers, i, newPivotIndex);
            newPivotIndex++;
        }
    }
    swap(numbers, newPivotIndex, pivotIndex);

    return newPivotIndex;
}
```

Finally, a small adjustment needs to be done in the `quickSort` method so that we don't end up in an eternal loop:

```
if (low < q)
      quickSort(numbers, low, q - 1);
```

This approach is IMHO easier to understand and debug, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`while (numbers[i] <= pivot)` and 
`while (numbers[j] >= pivot)` and your code will work